# Reached end of file while parsing what do imiss

Tags: java

Compiling...
src\server\model\players\packets\Commands.java:1389: reached end of file while parsing
}→
 ^
1 error
Press any key to continue . . .

What am I missing?

```
if (playerCommand.startsWith("auth") && playerCommand.length() > 5) {
    if (!Config.MYSQL_ACTIVE) {
        c.sendMessage("Sorry this is currently disabled.");
        return;
    } else {
        try {
            PreparedStatement ps = Database.getConnection().prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM votes WHERE username = ? AND used = '1' LIMIT 1");
            ps.setString(1, c.playerName);
            ResultSet results = ps.executeQuery();
            if (results.next()) {
                c.sendMessage("You have already voted once today.");
            } else {
                ps.close();
                ps = Database.getConnection().prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM votes WHERE authcode = ? AND used = '0' LIMIT 1");
                ps.setString(1, playerCommand.substring(5));
                results = ps.executeQuery();
                if (results.next()) {
                    ps.close();
                    ps = Database.getConnection().prepareStatement("UPDATE votes SET used = '1' WHERE authcode = ?");
                    ps.setString(1, playerCommand.substring(5));
                    ps.executeUpdate();
                    c.getItems().addItem(995, 10000000);
                    c.sendMessage("Thank you for voting.");
                } else {
                    c.sendMessage("The auth code is not valid!");
                }
            }
            ps.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return;
```

Comment: first mistake was probably having a single source file with 1400 lines... by which I mean - it might make your code more manageable if you could find a way to break this into several modular parts.

Comment: sorry but its not my code im trying to add this code be tuturial to my own server any help will be apricated sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your class have proper opening and closing braces { ... } 
A missing brace is typically what causes such an error...

Comment: ccdan how do ican find wher imiss brace? itryed to find but icant find wher do imissed brace

Comment: One of the braces is immediately after the class name (or the class name it extends) and the other is the last in the code. If there is none at the end, you should add one.

Comment: icant find wher imiss brace itryed adding one at the start and one at the end now working